# How to render all the content with React Snapshot?

Tags: reactjs, rendering, snapshot

I'm new with React and I'm trying to create a blog. For SEO reasons I'm using react-router, react-helmet, react-snapshot and a **static server** to see how Snapshot is rendering the code. Snapshot renders the page and the problem comes when I watch the source code: Snapshot only renders the preloaded code. As you can see in the next code, I show a loading text until the list of posts are loaded.

```
render() {
if (this.state.loaded) {
  let posts = this.state.posts;

  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map((post) => {
        return (
          <div key={post.slug}>
            <Link to={`/post/${post.slug}`}>{post.title}</Link>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
} else {
  return (
    <div>
      Loading...
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is what users see:
[This is what te users see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XuE8.png)

This is what Google sees:

```
<div data-reactid="4">
    <div data-reactid="5">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

Is there a solution to render all content?

Thanks,

Comment: did you fix this Issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend opening an issue on React Snapshot—I vaguely remember there was discussion of allowing longer timeouts when taking snapshots, therefore allowing your posts to be captured. https://github.com/geelen/react-snapshot/issues